# Loading DLL via GetModuleHandle/LoadLibrary and using FreeLibrary

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, api

here is my code:

```
function GetProcedureAddress(var P: FARPROC; const ModuleName, ProcName: AnsiString): Boolean;
var
  ModuleHandle: HMODULE;
begin
  Result := False;
  ModuleHandle := GetModuleHandle(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ModuleName)));
  if ModuleHandle = 0 then
    ModuleHandle := LoadLibrary(PAnsiChar(ModuleName)); // DO WE NEED TO CALL  FreeLibrary ?
  if ModuleHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    P := Pointer(GetProcAddress(ModuleHandle, PAnsiChar(ProcName)));
    if Assigned(P) then
      Result := True;
  end;
end;

function PathMakeSystemFolder(Path: AnsiString): Boolean;
var
  _PathMakeSystemFolderA: function(pszPath: PAnsiChar): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  Result := False;
  if GetProcedureAddress(@_PathMakeSystemFolderA, 'shlwapi.dll', 'PathMakeSystemFolderA') then
    Result := _PathMakeSystemFolderA(PChar(Path));
end;
```

DO we need to call FreeLibrary if using LoadLibrary? or it's reference count will decremented automatically when my application terminates?

Comment: You don't need to typecast an AnsiString to an AnsiString, I'm referring the ModuleName in GetProcedureAddress.

Comment: All objects acquired by process will be released upon its termination. However, is is good practice to release when no longer needed.

Comment: It would make more sense, to me, to call LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress once at program initialization time. And call freeLibrary at finalization. Or even use `delayed`. The use of GetModuleHandle just makes this code far far more complex than it needs to be and it is very wasteful to call GetProcAddress every time you want to call the API.

Comment: Be aware that `LoadLibrary` increments the reference count on that module, whereas `GetModuleHandle` does not increment the reference count.  Do **NOT** call `FreeLibrary` on a handle acquired via `GetModuleHandle`!  See the **Remarks** section for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will quote from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count).

So basically you don't need to call `FreeLibrary` but you should think about doing so. I personally think it is a bug when resources are not handled correctly.

Comment: yes but if I free the library, the GetModuleHandle will never work if the initial reference count was 0. so basically I'm only incrementing the reference count by 1 for my application considering that the module is not already mapped.

Comment: @kobik - It doesn't matter if you increase the reference count by 1 or 10, the dll will be mapped to process address space only once. There is no penalty using LoadLibrary against GetModuleHandle resource-wise. What the answer meant is that it is good practice to free the library when you're done with it.

Comment: so basically you are saying that using "GetModuleHandle" in my procuder is not needed? always use LoadLibrary?

Comment: @kobik - What I'm saying is, if you'll not free the library it won't make a difference.

Comment: @ Sertac Akyuz - I understood what the answer meant. I totally agree that one should free resources. I wanted to implement a generic procedure. it seems that ModuleHandle := GetModuleHandle(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ModuleName))); always return a Handle, and you cannot use FreeLibrary when using GetModuleHandle. the next line "ModuleHandle := LoadLibrary" is just in case that the module is not already mapped.

Comment: @kobik - I'm not saying your code is wrong or anything. I just thought you thought keeping the reference count at 1 is good for reserving resources. It's a misunderstanding on my part. We can delete this comment train if you'd like.

Comment: I think you may as well call `LoadLibrary` unless you go through this routine a lot - not likely. Also why are you restricting module names to be ANSI strings? No need for that. Restrict procedure names by all means, but it seems limiting for module names.

Comment: Towards your last sentence: "I personally think it is a bug when resources are not handled correctly", correctly, in the context of LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary, also includes allowing the automatic freeing based on process terminating. I'd suggest removing the sentence as it pushes the reader to possibly do more harm than good.